# Max&min of a sinus DF ; TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, for-loop, max, min, amplitude

I try to get the min & max spots of a Dataframe that is sinusoidal. The Frequency is in 400er steps.
I wanted to define the function amplitude and collect the data in an array. Amp1 is an abs max value that should be collected and added to the list.
After trying this code :

```
node1 = np.load( '1_v2_n.npy')
node2 = np.load( '2_v2_n.npy')
node3 = np.load( '3_v2_n.npy')
node4 = np.load( 'T_v2_n.npy')
```

At this part I get the failure :

```
def amplitude(array):
    for i in range (0,len(array),400):
        amp1[array]= abs(max(array[i:i+400]))
    return amp1[array]

print(amplitude(node1[0]))
```

I get the following output

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-d803767af22f> in <module>
      9     return amp1[array]
     10 
---> 11 print(amplitude(node1[0]))
     12 
     13 

<ipython-input-132-d803767af22f> in amplitude(array)
      6 def amplitude(array):
      7     for i in range (0,len(array),400):
----> 8         amp1[array]= abs(max(array[i:i+400]))
      9     return amp1[array]
     10 

TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

I tried to vary the return on different spots but it does not help.

Comment: can you provide a fully reproducible code? What are `amp1` and `array` (or `node`)?

Comment: I added the part before. I wanted to define the function amplitude and collect the data in an array. Amp1 is an abs max value that should be collected and added to the list.

Comment: As of now your code it not reproducible, I cannot copy/paste it and get the same error. The data is missing. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `amp1`should be defined somewhere in the function, as far as I understand that.

Comment: and `amp1[array]` is not going to work, I think.

Comment: first you could use print() to see what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: it seems `amp1[array]` is as function - so yo can't use `amp1[array] = ...` to assign some value. Where do you define `amp1` ?